# sudo apt-get-repository: command is not found in debian linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I was going to install firefox to debian linux. I used ubuntu command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
```

but i faced some errors it said

sudo apt-get-repository: command is not found.

So i cannot go forward to install firefox to my debian linux..

Could anyone tell me how to skip this problem and how to install firefox to debian

Comment: `add-apt-repository` is a command from Ubuntu Linux and its clones, as well as ppa repositories. In Debian you have to edit your file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, see a manual how to do it in Debian on Mozilla site.

Comment: which Debian version you're using?

Comment: @MichaelO. apt-get is the package handling utility that can work independently of any variant of Linux. It's part of Debian packaging some variant has different packaging utility.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check the Debian version what you're using. Debian by default comes with Iceweasel web browser instead of Firefox.

---

## How to install firefox in Debian Jessie,

1. Add Mozilla Archive to APT Repositories
   Open a terminal as root, and add a new file to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory`.

   `$ touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-mozilla.list`

edit this file in editor, `deb http://mozilla.debian.net/ jessie-backports firefox-release`

2. Add the Mozilla Archive Key
   This line adds mozilla.debian.net archive to your list of archives. Since the packages at mozilla.debian.net are signed, running apt-get update now will spit out a key not found the error. To add the key you need to download the p`kg-mozilla-archive-keyring package`, and install it. The package requires that debian-keying package be installed.

commands,

```
$ cd ~/
$ wget mozilla.debian.net/pkg-mozilla-archive-keyring_1.1_all.deb
$ dpkg -i pkg-mozilla-archive-keyring_1.1_all.deb
```

3. Install Firefox, update the archives and install Firefox:

commands,

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install -t jessie-backports firefox
```

After doing all the above steps you installed the Firefox.

---

## Installing Firefox browser on Debian wheezy

1. Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list file` and add the following line.

   `deb http://packages.linuxmint.com debian import`
2. Update your package list.

   `$ apt-get update`
3. The above command will fetch mint package repository list. As a last step install firefox browser.

   `$ apt-get install firefox`

---

Debian Jessie and later, another information if you use Jessie then it can be found in the software-properties-common package:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Whereas in Debian Wheezy and earlier, The apt-get program add-apt-repository is available in Debian.

That is located in the package: `python-software-properties`

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Actually, added to that package in version 0.75. The current version in Debian Stable ('squeeze") is 0.60, so it doesn't have it. The version currently in Debian Testing ("wheezy") is 0.82.7.1debian1, so it's available there

I request you to go through this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45879/how-to-add-repository-from-shell-in-debian), it will help you.

Comment: You can accept my answer by voting and checking the tick mark that is the big thanks you do in Stackoverflow :), your welcome.